# HTML5 drop down menu not hiding in iPhone simulator on click

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have a menu like this:

### HTML Code:

```
            <ul id="menu">                    
                <li><a href="#"><img src="images\menu.png"/></a>
                    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">OurSpace</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Corporate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Business Units</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Office Locations</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Global Expertise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Human Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Business Tools</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                   
            </ul>
```

### CSS:

```
     #menu
     {    
        margin: 0;  
        height: 35px;                     
        list-style: none;     

     }

     #menu li
     {
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
        position: relative;         
     }

     #menu a
     {
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        color: #000;
        font: 12px/25px Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica;
        text-decoration: none;               
     }

     #menu li:hover > a
     {
        color: #000;
     }

     #menu li:hover > ul
     {
        display: block;
     }

        /* Sub-menu */
     #menu ul
     {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 10px;
        width: 300%;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 35px;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;                 
        background: #D7DBDB;            
     }

     #menu ul li
     {
        float: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #ffffff;
     }       

     #menu ul a
     {  
        padding: 10px;
        height: auto;
        line-height: 1;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        float: none;
        text-transform: none;
     }

     #menu ul a:hover
     {
        //background: #0186ba;
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DBD9D9, #B8B2B2);
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #ffffff;

     }           
     #menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after
     {
        border-color: #04acec; 
     }         

     #menu:after
     {
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
     }
```

on hover, the menu opens up in the browser and hides after we move away. But the same is not working in iPhone simulator. On click, the menu opens but stays there forever. It is hiding only when I click on other tabs/anchor elements.

Comment: That is probably because iOS device does not understand hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a timer to hide the menu after x Sec, but you can't create a hover state for phones and tablet as Jamie Hutber explained well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

Phones do not have a hover state, per say. Everything is done with clicks sadly.

Think of it as if you were to move your finger over the phone you'll want to move the page, not move a cursor around on the page.